# PDF File does not open in JAR

Tags: java, pdf, netbeans, jar, stream

I am trying to open a PDF file when a button is clicked. However I can't seem to get this working when I run my program as a JAR.

Initially, I was using this code:

```
    if(Desktop.isDesktopSupported())
    {
        try
        {
            File myFile = new File("src/1. Handel - And the Glory of the Lord.pdf");
            Desktop.getDesktop().open(myFile);
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
        }
    }
```

That worked on Netbeans, however it didn't work on the JAR. After research, I found out its because I need to open it using a stream. Meaning I had to make a copy of it as a stream, and open that copy as a File. After looking around on stack overflow, I am now using this code:

```
    try {
        String inputPdf = "src/1. Handel - And the Glory of the Lord.pdf";
        InputStream manualAsStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(inputPdf);

        Path tempOutput = Files.createTempFile("1. Handel - And the Glory of the Lord", ".pdf");
        tempOutput.toFile().deleteOnExit();

        Files.copy(manualAsStream, tempOutput, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);

        File file = new File (tempOutput.toFile().getPath());
        if (file.exists())
        {
            Desktop.getDesktop().open(file);
        }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(HandelNotes.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

This does not even work on Netbeans, whilst on another thread on Stack Exchange, the user said it worked for them.

I am getting a java.lang.NullPointerException error, on this line:

```
Files.copy(manualAsStream, tempOutput, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

Does anyone know what's going wrong, and could someone please tell me how to correct my code?

Thanks,
Rohan

Comment: Have you tried opening a JAR and verifying that file is actually there under the specified path? (JAR is just a zip archive).

Comment: If I recall...I believe your first code block should have worked. Try placing the 'full path and file name' to the PDF file for the myFile declaration/initialization. At the very least you should have gotten a message box indicating the problem if there was an exception: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e.getMessage());

Comment: I know that the file actually exists, because if I go to the SRC folder under the project where the JAR is created, the file is there. Also, on Netbeans, the file does appear in the sidebar under the SRC folder.

When I run the first code block as a JAR there is a java.lang.IllegalArgumentException error, where it says the file does not exist.

I had a similar problem with audio and images, but I got them working using the GetResourceAsStream method.

After adding the showMessageDialog in my second block, when I run the file as a JAR, a message box still does not pop up.

Comment: Also, the original location of my file is google drive, so I've had to move all my files into the SRC folder so that they could be accessed on a JAR, which is why I am using the src/filename file path.

Comment: new File("src/1. Handel - And the Glory of the Lord.pdf") this is relative path and it used against directory from which u application starts. If u run from netbeans that it will be root directory of project, but jar i think in case of simple JavaApplication template in netbeans generated in builds directory.

Comment: If u use construction getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(inputPdf) class file must be located in same directory as pdf file. It is used in case if pack pdf file inside of jar file.

Comment: This statement will help u to find out where u are currently System.out.println(new File(".").getAbsolutePath())

Comment: In my Netbeans Project folder, my JAR resides in the dist folder, and all my resources reside in the SRC folder. I do not believe that they need to reside in the same folder, as I am also referencing images and audio files as streams, and they work fine from the SRC folder. I can be sure that the PDF files are being packed with the JAR, as when I open my program as a Jar file on another machine, my images and audio load fine, and the pdfs are in the same folder.

Comment: I've tried changing the "InputStream ManualAsStream" line above to:

InputStream manualAsStream = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(inputPdf);

Nothing seems to have changed, and I still seem to be getting a NullPointerException error for  the following line:

Files.copy(manualAsStream, tempOutput, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);

From my understanding, this code is converting the PDF to a stream, and then making a copy of that stream as a File so that it can be opened using:

Desktop.getDesktop().open(file);

I'm still confused as to where my problem lies.